# Convex optimisation under linear inequality constraints

Tags: algorithms, optimization

What are the fastest known algorithms for general convex optimisation under linear inequality constraints?

Comment: That's a pretty wide question...

Comment: In which direction would you like to see it narrowed?

Comment: It shouldn't necessarily be narrowed - but the answer should be a mini-survey.